# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a csv file as list in this python program. The file test.csv contains only one row of various numbers. I want to find the possible combination of numbers whose sum is equal to 500 and after getting output as a list the python program will append this list in my test.csv file.

csv_file.py

```
import sys
import csv
import os

file_name="test.csv"
path1 = "C:\MAYANK\python p"
path2 = os.path.join(path1, file_name)

with open(path2, 'r') as csv_file:
   reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
   row1 = list(reader)


def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=list()):
    s = sum(partial)
    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target:
        with open(path2, 'a') as csv_file1:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file1)
        writer.writerow(partial)

    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subset_sum(row1, 500)
```

I have written all code but getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "csv_file.py", line 33, in <module>
 subset_sum(row1, 500)
File "csv_file.py", line 30, in subset_sum
 subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
File "csv_file.py", line 17, in subset_sum
  s = sum(partial)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: This function works fine on valid input, so you're not getting that input in properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(path2, 'r') as csv_file:
   reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
   row1 = list(reader)
```

Your input/how you're importing it is your problem:

```
>>> subset_sum([111,222,333,444,555, 499, 1, 389, 20, 369], 500)
[111, 389]
[111, 20, 369]
[499, 1]
```

works, while:

```
>>> subset_sum([111,222,333,444,555, [499], 1, 389, 20, 369], 500)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

does not.

`reader` must be a nested list which then `sum([[]])` gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`

**after you fix your input**, you'll likely get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

which means you need to map that list to ints. To fix this would be replacing the `list()` call with `map(int, )`:

```
with open(path2, 'r') as csv_file:
   reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
   row1 = map(int, reader)
```

Comment: `list(something_that_is_already_a_list)`  doesn't increase nesting, it just copies the list contents into a new container.   I think the problem is that `reader` is *already* a nested sequence, even before `list(reader)`.

Comment: which in turn would mean that you can't `map(int, ...)` it directly.

Comment: @jez I did mention *after you fix your input*. Without knowing what the csv file looks like, we can only guess at how best to fix it.

Comment: i fixed my input by `reader1 = list(reader)[0]` and  which is showing me error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' `after that i used `row1 = map(int, reader1)` but this is giving me another error `object of type 'map' has no len()`

Comment: @MayankJain Edit your post and add your code with changes. Also, when you get an error like that, it helps to include the line it occurs on.

Answer (score 0):

`list(reader)`  gives you a list of rows, where each row is a list of strings. In other words, your `row1` is a **list of lists**, not a list of numbers, which is why `sum()` throws that particular exception.

The fact that you have named it `row1` suggests that you are only interested in the first row.  If so,  then you actually mean to say `row1 = list(reader)[0]` and that would give you a list that `sum()` can work on.  But beware that you'll lose access to the rest of the table if you do that.

A second problem is that you need to convert the individual entries from strings to numbers, otherwise you won't get the result you're presumably expecting from `sum()`.

To preserve the whole table while converting it from strings to numbers, you could do this:

```
with open(path2, 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    table = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in reader]
    row1 = table[0]
```

and then carry on as before.

Comment: i used your code but it is giving me error `could not convert string to float: ` . my csv file  contains various numbers separated by comma like `100,200,300,400,200,40,30,440,899,344,440,100,100`

Comment: Use the list comprehension version from the command line, and when you can this error ask it what `x` is. It'll be something that can't be converted to `float`.   Program around that. You may have to write your own `def convert(x)` function to handle the exceptional cases gracefully, and use that in place of `float()`.